# Simple expect once with arguments

Tags: mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to get this simple test to work.

```
let querySpy = sinon.spy(db.query);

querySpy.expects().once().withArgs(`USE myDatabase`);
```

I'm trying to put a spy on a method, expect it to be called once with specific arguments. Easier said than done.

I cannot put the spy on `db`, results in `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function` (it's an object).

I'm looking at: https://gist.github.com/yoavniran/1e3b0162e1545055429e#sinon-chai

I can't find a `calledOnceWith` method. Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **args** to verify the arguments that are sent to the function.

```
 sinon.spy(db, "query");  //spy on existing method     
 expect(db.query.calledOnce).to.be.true; //verify is called once
 const args = db.query.getCalls()[0].args; //get the arguments
 expect(args[0]).to.equal(`USE myDatabase`); //verify the arguments.
```

This is one way to verify args.